# Flask - Flask-Moment gives out an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: datetime, flask, momentjs

Ok, so i want to change a datetime value from mysql database into a desired format. so my code goes:

```
file: app.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, request, logging
from datetime import datetime
from flask_moment import Moment

app = Flask(__name__)
moment = Moment(app)
mysql = MySQL(cursorclass=DictCursor)

@app.route('/users')
def users():

# create cursor
cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()

# execute query
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')

# get results
users = cur.fetchall()

return render_template('users.html', title = 'User Accounts', users=users)
```

then on my users.html, i display the datetime value on a table which goes:

```
file: users.html
<tbody>
    {% for row in users %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{row.id}}</td>
            <td>{{row.username}}</td>
            <td>{{row.fullname}}</td>
            <td>{{moment(row.created_at).format('LLL')}}</td> # this causes an error
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

But when i put in the following code for the datetime:

```
<td>{{moment().format('LLL')}}</td> # this is working
```

So in short,

```
# this is not working
# Causes an "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'" error
moment(row.created_at).format('LLL') 

# this is working 
# but i can't modify the data based on the value from mysql database
moment().format('LLL') 

# by the way, this is also not working
# and it also causes the same error
row.created_at.strftime('%M %d, %Y')
```

What i need to know is how to format datetime value in the flask template and Flask-Moment seems to be the only way

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You can also try using:

```
{{ row.created_at.strftime('%M %d, %Y') }}
```

or the jinja datetime filter:

```
{{ row.created_at|datetime }}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

It appears you need to convert from MySQL DateTime to Python datetime. Without seeing more of your code, maybe something like this would work, though there is probably a more efficient way:

```
# get results
users = cur.fetchall()

for user in users:
    user.created_at = datetime.strptime(user.created_at, '%Y-%M-%d') # you have to use the mysql format here

return render_template('users.html', title = 'User Accounts', users=users)
```

You are using `strftime` when it appears that python is interpreting the MySQL `datetime` as a string, not a `datetime()` object, so you have to use `strptime`

Comment: TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime... this is the new error it shows

Comment: There may be something wrong with your moment installation or code, without seeing more it's hard to help.

Comment: Are you trying to use the javascript Moment library or the flask one in your code? You can't use javascript inside {{ }} blocks.

Comment: I updated my answer. There are several ways to do it without having to use Flask-Moment

Comment: i'm not really sure, i only followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-moment/)

Answer (score 0):

Momentjs couldn't parse it because it is an 'str'. Use datetime to parse the string before  passing it to the momentjs  object e.g

```
from datetime import datetime
row_created_at = datetime.strptime(row_created_at, %m %d,%Y ')
```

then pass it to the momentjs object like so

```
{{moment(row_created).format("LLL")}}
```

That should do the trick